# Upload a file into drive using google apss script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I am trying to upload a image file into google drive...
Code ;

```js
function upload() {
  var url= // url for image
  var contents=UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContent()   // trying to get image content
  var base = 'https://docs.google.com/feeds' 
  var fetchArgs = googleOAuth_('docs', base);
  fetchArgs.method='POST'
  fetchArgs.contentType='image/jpeg'
  var xml={title :"image",content:contents}
  fetchArgs.payload=xml
  var fileURL='https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=media'
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(fileURL, fetchArgs)
}

function googleOAuth_(name,scope) {
  var oAuthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService(name);
  oAuthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope="+scope);
  oAuthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken");
  oAuthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken");
  oAuthConfig.setConsumerKey(consumerKey);
  oAuthConfig.setConsumerSecret(consumerSecret);
  return {oAuthServiceName:name, oAuthUseToken:"always"};
}
```

When I am running this code, I am getting this error :

Request failed for returned code 403. Server response: { "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "usageLimits", "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg", "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.", "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console" } ], "code": 403, "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup." } }

What am i doing wrong, I am not getting this....Please give me some feasible solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's wrong with this:

```
DocsList.createFile(UrlFetchApp.fetch(fileURL, fetchArgs));
```

As a replacement for that entire code?

Comment: If I want to upload file from user account to admin account's drive, then you one line code will not work.....Then I have to use my above code, but it is creating error....so what is solution for this ????

Comment: If you are getting the error above, read what it says... you are over some quota limit. That error is coming from the drive api, not from apps script; you'll have to look at that documentation for help.

Comment: But I run above code only once, and I got this error.. One time run and i got quota limit error,  it is bit confusing....:(

Comment: 1) Still not an Apps Script question - you need to ask people who know the Drive apis. 2) Perhaps the quota is 0 without registration? That's how I'd interpret the message.